# Símbolo grego teta inserindo no SQL

Tags: sql

Temos uma aplicação aqui no trabalho onde geramos algumas telas em angularjs e guardamos em banco de dados para termos um fluxo fácil de implantação em ambiente produtivo.

Só que ao adicionar a tela ao banco de dados (SQL) ele converte o símbolo grego teta que é utilizado no angular, em um código ï e depois quando solicitamos essa tela do banco, fica com esse código ï e logicamente, não funciona a tela.

Alguém saberia me dizer como posso fazer o SQL não converter esse símbolo grego?

Comment: Qual a _collation_ que tem a sua instância SQL? Que tipo é a coluna onde está a armazenar o texto? Fazendo a consulta diretamente no SQL, devolve corretamente?

Comment: Quais são as codificações de caracteres utilizadas na aplicação e no banco de dados?